# Why do I get Unreachable Code in this situation?

Tags: java

Why I try to use the loop to display the numbers I had put into the `ArrayList`, it says Unreachable code what am I doing wrong.

```
private void nOther1() {

    ArrayList<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<Integer>();              
    int n = 1;            
    while (1 <= 100) {                
        multiples.add(n);
        n++;                                  
    } 

    // UNREACHABLE CODE
    for (int num : multiples) {
          System.out.println(num);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Change `while(1 <= 100)` to `while(n <= 100)`

Comment: I just caught on thank you

Answer (score 10):

Because

```
while (1 <= 100)
```

will never terminate since 1 is always <= 100, and the compiler knows that.

See Chapter [14.21. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) for detailed explanation.

Comment: 39 seconds; that was fast!

Answer (score 0):

This condition `while(1 <= 100){`    is always returning `true`

it would be the same as you do `while(true){`  so all behind that point is code that NEVER will be executed..

I think you wanted trying instead:

```
while(n <= 100){                
              multiples.add(n);
              n++;                                
 }
```